# Chart Width no render ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

im working in a proyect, and im trying to build some charts, im using HighCharts jQuery library, i split the charts or graph in rows>colunms>containers.
On the HighCharts jQuery library demos, they put the charts in a div width inline style, like this:

```
<div id="container1" style="width: 310px; max-width: 800px;
height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

My issue is that, when the chart is loaded it always have a width of 310px, no mater the widt of my screen but when a resize my screen its render ok, i need this proyect to work responsive and so on in a mobile i cannot resize the screen, someone could helpme?

Comment: the reason is you give static width to div if you use width in percentage that will work for you

Comment: i already tried it and not work, when i use percentage the chart overlap the div where its inside, and when a resize the screen i get fix

Comment: see the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/4cpsczdt/1/

Comment: Set the float:left; for container chart. It looks like outer continaer is float but inside not. If problem still appears, please update the @Zubairsadiq example to introduce issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4cpsczdt/1/)

Html code

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1" style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px;
height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS code

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
    renderTo: 'container1'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 0, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
}]

});
```

Comment: getting the same problen in a diferent way, look at here https://jsfiddle.net/2jn2m6vq/, this is part of the code of the chart, the script now is setting the width og the childs for content with a fixed width of the max-width, if a setup fixed min width it then setup to the min width